# Apache not starting after upgrade wampserver Php from 7.2.4 to 8.01

Tags: php, wamp

this is the error i get 'The line 'zend_extension=.dll' exists in php.ini file but there is no .dll' file' but i do not any such line in my .ini file. What could be the problem?

Comment: "What could be the problem?" - sounds like your configuration is broken. Did you search in **all** possible ini files?

Comment: That belongs in the `php.ini`. Look in there, do a search for `zend_extension` there are normall only 2, one in the `[opcache]` section and the other is the `[xdebug]` section. Show us the broken line and I will give you the correct fix

Comment: Also, what version of WAMPPServer are you running please

Comment: 3.1.3 64bit version

Comment: Yes, so how about the other comment?

Comment: so edit `wamp64\bin\php\php8.0.1\phpForApache.ini` and show me any line that has `zend_extention` in it

Comment: these are the lines in the phpForApache.ini - zend_extension=php_opcache.dll; 
zend_extension=php_xdebug.dll

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the same issue using this:

1. enter https://xdebug.org/download/historical
2. there will be 4 different variations for same PHP version. try one by one, it might be 64 bit, or 32 bit, Thread-Safe or Non-Thread-Safe.

don't forget to restart Wamp everytime after you place dll file in `/ext` folder, and then click `Wamp > PHP > PHP Extensions` and check if XDEBUG is green checkmarked.